# replace .jpg url to .mp4 new extention in php

Tags: php

I am hoping someone can offer some advice.

I have image location (example) src="http://www.abc.com/uploads/images/name123.jpg" (i'm using the image already)

I now have a videos for every image I have named the video the same as the images and want to continue to use the image on the page

ie: http://www.abc.com/uploads/videos/name123.mp4

please help if you can, hopefully some elegant string replace function?

Comment: could you share some code? how are you getting the original image string name?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to replace'.jpg' to '.mp4', try use `str_replace()`.

```
 $src="http://www.example.com/uploads/images/name123.jpg";
$src2 = str_replace('.jpg', '.mp4', $src);
echo $src2;
```

Comment: it is `str_replace` not `str_rplace`.

Comment: ahh thank you, that solves one problem. if i need to pull the renamed video from a new url path?